# Role of " * " in operator overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I've got this code snippet but I am not quite sure why I should put an asterisk before "this" when I am overloading the += operator. "this" is a pointer. Does the asterisk dereference the "this" keyword? If yes, then what does it mean? My guess is that since "this" is a pointer to the object, by dereferencing it I am getting the address of the memory where the object is, so the compiler implicitly saves the address in a temp and I am returning the temp as a reference. Is my understanding correct?

```
#include <iostream>

class Account {
   public:
    explicit Account(double b) : balance(b) {}
    Account& operator+=(double b) {
        balance += b;
        return *this;
    }
    friend Account& operator+=(Account& a, Account& b);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Account& a);

   private:
    double balance;
};
```

Comment: You are returning `Account&` and in order to convert from `Account*` (`this`) you need to dereference that pointer `*`.

Comment: `*this` just means "the object the `this` pointer points to". It is not a copy or a temporary, it is just that object.

Comment: In the design & evolution of C++, the `this` was made to be a *pointer to the instance* rather than a *reference to the instance* because pointers predate references.  References were introduced much later.

Answer (score 3):

> *Does the asterisk dereference the "this" keyword?*

Yes.

> *The keyword `this` is a rvalue(until C++11) prvalue(since C++11) expression **whose value is the address of the implicit object** parameter (object on which the non-static member function is being called).*

That being the case, when dereferencing it you will be returning the object and not its address, as a *normal* pointer.

> *My guess is that since "this" is a pointer to the object, by dereferencing it I am getting the address of the memory where the object is...*

It's the opposite, had you not dereferenced it you would be returning the address, by dereferencing it you're returning the object, *i.e.* the value stored in that address.

> *I've got this code snippet but I am not quite sure why I should put an asterisk before "this" when I am overloading the `+=` operator.*

Given the above explanations and knowing  the `+=` operator is used to add and assign values, why would you not dereference `this` and return an address? It wouldn't make sense.